# Non-isomorphic graphs with diameter two

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $n>1$ be an integer and $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$. What is an example of non-isomorphic simple, undirected graphs $G_i = ([n], E_i)$ for $i=1,2$ with the following properties?

1. both $G_1$ and $G_2$ have [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) two,
2. $\chi(G_1)=\chi(G_2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K_n$ without edge and $K_n$ without two edges which share a common vertex (well, if $n>3$). In both cases $\chi=n-1$.

Comment: Indeed, there are no examples for n less than 4.  Another pair of graphs with chromatic number two are bipartite: a star graph and a diamond graph (K1,n-1 and K2,n-2).  Complete bipartite graphs should provide enough examples with small chromatic number and diameter two. Gerhard "Not Like Stars And Bars" Paseman, 2018.03.19.

Answer (score 5):

A random graph $G(n,1/2)$ has diameter $2$ almost surely, and there is an integer $\ell$ such that, almost surely, its chromatic number is $\ell$
or $\ell+1$. (See  [Achlioptas and Naor - The two possible values of the chromatic number of a random graph](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/chromatic.pdf).)

So there are rather a lot of examples.

Comment: has diameter *two* almost surely